# Chromium extension: restore previous state

Tags: chrome, chromium-os

I cleaned Chromium browser's browsing data, but I made a mistake not backing up a Nifty wallet extension.

I would like to know how can I restore the previous state, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Additional details on how you cleaned your profile are needed, but mostly restoring an extension datas if its files are deleted is a very hard task, if not impossible especially if the computer is being used, as disk I/O may make residual data overwritten on the system's storage disk which would make any recovery impossible.

You may open an issue [here](https://github.com/poanetwork/nifty-wallet/issues) with all the technical details.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to search for a deleted file...but then I noticed that the wallet vault keystore still there... I'm trying to restore it following the suggestions in this other open issue, but with several differences because Im on Linux: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/52658/where-does-metamask-store-the-wallet-seed-file-path

Comment: No, I was not able to restore the wallet from the .ldb files. I was able to extract the key from the current wallets, and to decode for recovering the seed phrase. But the "deleted" one was not there. I guess it must be any wa to restore chrome/chromium to previous state...